# Devpartner Coverage report 3rd party tool

Tags: code-coverage, devpartner

Does anyone know if there is a tool for analyzing coverage data from Devpartner.
My report comes with an extention ".dpcov", I can convert it to xml only. Has anyone worked on such xml to make a nicer view like html?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the DevPartner developers speaking here.  First of all, I am not aware of any third-party product, open source or shareware that will do what you want.

Secondly, have you tried using the DevPartner report generator?  To do this, follow these steps:
(1) Open and select the .DPCOV file in Visual Studio.
(2) Use the File / Export DevPartner Data... command to generate the XML file.
(3) Use the File / Prepare DevPartner Report... command to launch the report generator applet.
(4) Select the report template "Code Coverage Report".
(5) Enter your name as the author of the report.
(6) Select the code coverage session XML file.
(7) Press the "Generate Report" button.

The result will look something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a547puhtedoo1tj/codecoveragereport.png?dl=0).

Beyond that, I have some code which can read the XML file and do a quick "Is everything covered, true or false?" type of analysis.  I can give you this code if you wish.

Addition: The batch commands to convert the DPCOV file to XML, and from there to HTML:

```
REM Export the coverage file to XML
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\DevPartner Studio\Analysis\DevPartner.Analysis.DataExport.exe" %1.dpcov /nologo

REM Generate the Coverage Report
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\DevPartner Studio\DPRender\dprender.exe" /Console /Template:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\DevPartner Studio\DPRender\Templates\CodeCoverageReport.dprtemplate" /output:%1.html  /Prop:docCoverageFile{file}=%1.dpcov
```

Comment: FWIW, all the steps above can be done from a command prompt, and so can be made into a batch file.

Comment: I love you man. That's some nice html page I exported. Thank you! Is it possible to get more info into that html? Like files with covered lines etc (like the dpcov file). Also send me the code you have for parsing xml please. Thank you very very much

Comment: Can you also send me batch example to get that report automatically? Thanks!